# AKS - Kubernetes service, helm upgrade get failed on release pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

Created Azure devops project to deploy on aks with "Bring your own code" options it has created CI, CD pipeline by default with helm charts.

Pipeline build got succeed with helm charts, but in release CD got error related to helm upgrade, not able to get any clue on same.

I am newbie to helm charts and aks. Logs are below.
Thanks

[Azure devops project release CD logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlF9G.png)

[Helm upgrade command logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU52I.png)

[Output of kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL5cU.png)

Comment: show output for kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide. Assume you  already have service with the same name. Probably you will need to delete ols service and then you'll be able to create what you want.

Comment: @VKR, yes you are right service is already there, but i have not touch any thing it is created by Azure pipeline CD i think. can you suggest how to remove it before do new release.
**Question updated for output of  kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide**

Comment: maybe this is of help? https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2947

Comment: `kubectl delete svc servicesbuilding -n dev`

Comment: @VKR, ok mentioned command will do job, but i have aks pipeline should i able to set this command in it. or i have to do manually? 
aks CD pipeline has default defined stage, how can i define this command in aks CD. 
If i automate it will be good.

Comment: @MarkusDresch, means service name should not be more than 14 char?